Problem with VBA VLookup not working for some values
I have a workbook with sheet1 containing words in column A and sheet2 where in column A is a word form sheet1 and in B is a corresponding code.
I need to VLookup the the code from sheet2 to the same word in sheet1. The code I am using is matching almost all, but singular letters and digits. When I try to VLookup it manually I don't have any problems.
How can I fix that?
All cells are formatted the same and don't have any spaces.
UPDATED                                                                                                     Sub VlookupFinalForAllColumns_WithFormatting()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowSource As Long
    Dim lastColSource As Long
    Dim lastRowTarget As Long
    Dim lookupValue As String
    Dim finalValue As Variant
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim lookupRange As Range
    Dim outputCol As Long
    Dim headerRow As Long
    Dim currentCol As Long
    Dim resultCol As Long
    Dim firstResultOffset As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    
    headerRow = 1 ' Row containing headers in Sheet1
    
    ' Set worksheets
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Sheet1 with data
    Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") ' Sheet2 with "Final" column
    
    ' Find the last row and column in Sheet1 (data starts from B2)
    lastRowSource = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row ' Last row in column B
    lastColSource = wsSource.Cells(headerRow, wsSource.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' Last used column in the header row
    
    ' Find the last row in Sheet2
    lastRowTarget = wsTarget.Cells(wsTarget.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' Last row in column A of Sheet2
    
    ' Format all cells in Sheet1 (data) and Sheet2 (lookup range) to be Text and Trim them
    ' Format and trim Sheet1 (source data)
    For i = 2 To lastRowSource
        For j = 2 To lastColSource
            wsSource.Cells(i, j).Value = Trim(CStr(wsSource.Cells(i, j).Value)) ' Convert to text and trim
            wsSource.Cells(i, j).NumberFormat = "@" ' Set format to Text
        Next j
    Next i
    
    ' Format and trim Sheet2 (lookup data)
    For i = 2 To lastRowTarget
        wsTarget.Cells(i, 1).Value = Trim(CStr(wsTarget.Cells(i, 1).Value)) ' Convert column A to text and trim
        wsTarget.Cells(i, 2).Value = Trim(CStr(wsTarget.Cells(i, 2).Value)) ' Convert column B to text and trim
        wsTarget.Cells(i, 1).NumberFormat = "@" ' Set format to Text
        wsTarget.Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = "@" ' Set format to Text
    Next i
    
    ' Define the lookup range from Sheet2 (lookup in column A, return from column B)
    Set lookupRange = wsTarget.Range("A2:B" & lastRowTarget)
    
    ' Initialize firstResultOffset to place results 3 columns after the last used column
    firstResultOffset = lastColSource + 3
    resultCol = firstResultOffset ' The first result column will be placed here
    
    ' Loop through each data column in Sheet1, starting from column B (col 2)
    For currentCol = 2 To lastColSource
        ' Set the header for the current column result in Sheet1
        wsSource.Cells(headerRow, resultCol).Value = wsSource.Cells(headerRow, currentCol).Value & "Final"
        
        ' Loop through each row in the current column
        For Each cell In wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(2, currentCol), wsSource.Cells(lastRowSource, currentCol))
            lookupValue = Trim(CStr(cell.Value)) ' Ensure the lookup value is treated as text and trimmed
            
            ' Perform VLOOKUP for the current cell's value, treating everything as text
            finalValue = Application.VLookup(lookupValue, lookupRange, 2, False)
            
            
            ' If a match is found, place it in the resultCol column
            If Not IsError(finalValue) Then
                cell.Offset(0, resultCol - currentCol).Value = finalValue
            Else
                ' If no match found, output #N/A
                cell.Offset(0, resultCol - currentCol).Value = ""
            End If
        Next cell
        
        ' Move resultCol for the next column (no additional spacing after the first result)
        resultCol = resultCol + 1
    Next currentCol
    
    MsgBox "VLOOKUP matching completed with formatting and trimming for all columns in Sheet1!", vbInformation
End Sub



Remove the On Error Resume Next and On Error Goto 0 lines, Give an example of a value that does not match. How are the cells formatted ?

lookupValue = CStr(Trim(cell.Value)) maybe your source data has extra spaces missing from your lookup value?

FYI - unlike Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup, Application.VLookup doesn't cause a runtime error if there's no match, so the On Error Resume next is redundant.

I removed On Error Resume Next. A few examples of values that didn't match are 0, 2, 1 and letters - Y, G. The cells are formatted as General, I tried to format them as text too but with no result.

If lookupValue is "3" (ie. a string) then it will not match the number 3 on a worksheet but it will match "3" (number stored as text)   If you have mixed values in your lookup column then it's best to format them all as text before running your lookups.  You should not be having any issues with single letters though, unless there are extra spaces or other characters in the "matched" worksheet cells

Why don't you try using a VLookup formula in column C to see if it's working as a cell formula.  If it works there then something's wrong with your VB.

It's working when I do it manually. I will dabble-check if it's a string.

If you format cells as text you may need to re-enter the cell values for the formatting to "take"

I changed the code a little (I updated it in my initial post for you to see) and now the digits are matching but the singular letters are still not matched.

There's no problem with match single letters in any of my testing, so there's something in your actual data which we're not able to see...  In your For i = 2 To lastRowTarget loop I would set the numberformat before trimming the values, since you sometimes have to re-enter the cell value after setting it to Text before the new format is recognized.

It was indeed in my data, there are cells that separate the data alphabetically and the vlookup was taking a blank cell.

Good to hear you figured it out.
